# querying multiple tables order by time in tables

Tags: mysql, union

Actually I am stuck in middle of some mysql code. Can anyone suggest a simple question. I have 6-10 (multiple) tables in a database all having different data means not related to each other.

There is no relation between tables, but have posted time inserted in each of the columns of all the tables. All I want is query all the tables sorted by timed column.

Eg:
table1:

```
recipename | cook | timetocook | dated (auto posted time - php time())
-----------+------+------------+------
abc        | def  |        100 | 10
zxy        | orp  |        102 | 16
```

table2:

```
bookname | author | dated (auto posted time - php time())
---------+--------+------
ab       | cd     | 11
ef       | nm     | 14
```

As you can see there is no relation between the table (I have read about joins), I want to show data one by one according to the posted time asc to desc.

like this:

```
abc  def  100  10
ab   cd   11
ef   nm   14
zxy  orp  102  16
```

So any help...to achieve this ???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT recipename, cook, timetocook, dated 
FROM table1
UNION 
SELECT bookname, author, dated, NULL
FROM table2
ORDER BY dated
```

You have to add **NULL** value to make sure the column counts is the same the order tables.

Comment: No problem. If my answer helped you, simply mark it as solution